# Removing a backslash from an apostrophe in PHP

Tags: php

The code below allows the user to enter in a phrase in plain English, which is then added to a database as "$site". If the user enters in an apostrophe, the phrase is stored with a backslash in front of the apostrophe. How can I get the variable "$site" to be added to the database without backslashes in front of apostrophes?

```
print "<div class=\"siteadd\">
          <form action='process.php?find=$find1' method='post'>
              Add a book to this topic: <input name='site' type='text' size='50'>
              <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
          </form>
       </div>";
```

Then, in process.php:

```
$site = str_replace($remove_array, "", $_POST['site']);
$site = strtolower($site);
$site = mysql_real_escape_string($site);
$illegal = array("/", "\"");
$site = str_replace($illegal, '', $site);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$find` VALUES (NULL, '$site',1,0)");
```

Comment: Related: *[With “magic quotes” disabled, why does PHP/WordPress continue to auto-escape my POST data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949768)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume the backslash is added by PHP for security reasons. Read more about [magic quotes](http://pl.php.net/magic_quotes). And since you’re using the proper function to escape strings passed to mysql queries, you don’t have to rely on PHP’s dummy escaping.

At the beginning of the script, check if `magic_quotes` are on, and if so, remove the slashes:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    function stripslashes_deep($value)
    {
        $value = is_array($value) ?
                    array_map('stripslashes_deep', $value) :
                    stripslashes($value);

        return $value;
    }

    $_POST = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_POST);
    $_GET = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_GET);
    $_COOKIE = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_COOKIE);
    $_REQUEST = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_REQUEST);
}
```

BTW, in your code, `$find` variable comes from an untrusted source and should be escaped/filtered as well.

Comment: Thanks... this works.  And I added "mysql_real_escape_string" to $find.

Comment: You should check if $find is on your whitelist. You don’t want to let anyone add data to *any* table in your database, do you?

Answer (score 1):

The call to `mysql_real_escape_string()` is probably the reason (https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string), but you might also have Magic Quotes enabled on your server (http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php).

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string() was [removed in PHP 7.0.0](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string), and magic quotes were [removed in PHP 5.4.0](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`mysqli::prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), and then use `bind_param` on the resulting `mysqli_stmt`. This will prevent other types of [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) as well.